# django database sync problem

Tags: django, django-models

In my web django, I do a query of Models.objects.all() or actually any other models in the views.py. It returns me a [,] value (empty array) - view from logs. However back in the manage.py shell, it is able to retrieve the objects. In mysql database, the data entries are there!

I have no idea how to debug from here, is there a way to resolve this error? This is not my first time. I have been doing django project for several months already. Only today, it is giving me this problem.

EDIT : This problem is very weird, I'm just curious whether anybody has encountered this problem before, I'm using Eclipse to edit the scripts(views.py, models.py etc).

Comment: Have you tried using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and trying in the debugger?

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am seeing a similar problem, with ORACLE.  I can add entries with the SQL plain interface, but the django classes do not see them.  However, if I add an entry to the database with the django save() call, those can be seen.
Bottom line: If an entry is added to the database with a django save() call, the django objects.all() will retrieve it, but entries added with plain SQL are not retrieved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `__repr__` defined for your objects? Take a look at the HTML source generated by Django -- there's a good chance it looks like:

```
[<Model: model object>, <Model: model object>, ...]
```

Your web browser then interprets the <...> as an HTML tag that it doesn't understand, and thus can't render, and displays only the content outside the tags (the "[", ",", and "]" characters).